# Store time and errors of batch script in text file

Tags: mysql, windows, batch-file

I have a batch script test.bat and a text file log.txt which store errors of my test.bat.

I am using `2>> log.txt` to store the errors at the end of my commands.

For example : `mysql -u root -padmin -e "stop slave;" 2>> log.txt`

And my log.txt display `mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command` so it's works fine.

I just want to know if it is possible to add the time before the error message in the log.txt like `20:51:23 mysql is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I tried things like

`%time%2>> log.txt`

or

```
set time=%time%
time2>> log.txt
```

But it doesn't work. Any ideas ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The echo set option echo's time without newline. so it will echo time and then the message right next to it.

```
echo|set /p= %time% >> log.txt
mysql -u root -padmin -e "stop slave;" 2>> log.txt
```

Comment: pleasure, glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

just try `echo %TIME% >> log.txt`

Comment: yes, but that will just echo the time including new line with the error below it

Comment: You're right. The requirement for the same line somehow eluded me maybe because of the line break. +1 for your answer.